# Close all File Handles when Calling posix_spawn

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, posix

I'd like to spawn a collection of processes using posix_spawn(...) (or something very similar). This function accept an argument of type posix_spawn_file_actions_t, which allows me specify how the open file handles should be treated. From what I can ascertain from [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn), all files are inherited from the calling processes and modified according the information in the posix_spawn_file_actions_t structure.

I want all files to be unopened by the spawned process (except for stdin, stdout, and stderr). Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Apparently this can be done on some implementations usinf the 'POSIX_SPAWN_CLOEXEC_DEFAULT' spawn attribute flag, but this isn't available on my platform. I could also use [fcntl(...)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) to specify 'close on exec' whenever I open a file, but I feel that a more localised solution to this problem would be preferable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open file descriptor handling over [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`exec*()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) in a multithreaded application using file leases and/or `fcntl()` locks (record locks) is dicey.

In general, the [`O_CLOEXEC`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)/[`fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) option is preferable over explicitly closing the descriptors, as explicitly closing a descriptor has some undesirable side effects. In particular, if you have a lease on the descriptor, closing the descriptor in the child process will release the lease.

Note that in Linux, `fcntl()` locks are not inherited across a `fork()`; see Description in [man 2 fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

[`posix_spawn()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn) is implemented in the C library, and the file actions can be managed by [`posix_spawn_file_actions_init()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn_file_actions_init), [`posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose) et cetera; look at the *See also* list in the man pages. Personally, I would not use this interface, as closing the descriptors in the child process prior to `exec*()` is at least as simple.

Because of all of the above, I personally prefer to open files with `O_CLOEXEC` and/or use `fcntl(fd,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC)` so that all descriptors are close-on-exec by default. Something like

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void set_all_close_on_exec(void)
{
    struct rlimit  rlim;
    long           max;
    int            fd;

    /* Resource limit? */
#if defined(RLIMIT_NOFILE)
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rlim) != 0)
        rlim.rlim_max = 0;
#elif defined(RLIMIT_OFILE)
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_OFILE, &rlim) != 0)
        rlim.rlim_max = 0;
#else
    /* POSIX: 8 message queues, 20 files, 8 streams */
    rlim.rlim_max = 36;
#endif

    /* Configured limit? */
#if defined(_SC_OPEN_MAX)
    max = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
#else
    max = 36L;
#endif

    /* Use the bigger of the two. */
    if ((int)max > (int)rlim.rlim_max)
        fd = max;
    else
        fd = rlim.rlim_max;

    while (fd-->0)
        if (fd != STDIN_FILENO  &&
            fd != STDOUT_FILENO &&
            fd != STDERR_FILENO)
            fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
}
```

is a pretty portable way to quickly set all open descriptors (except standard ones) to close-on-exec; libraries sometimes use descriptors internally, and may not set `O_CLOEXEC`. On my system, `set_all_close_on_exec()` takes 0.25ms to run; the maximums are 4096 and 1024 respectively, so it ends up trying to set 4093 file descriptors.

(Note that `fcntl(fd,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC)` should succeed for all valid descriptors, and fail with `errno==EBADF` for other (invalid/unused) descriptors.)

Note that it is much faster to simply try setting the flag on all possible descriptors, than to try and find out which descriptors are actually open. (The latter is possible in Linux via e.g. `/proc/self/fd/`.)

Second, I prefer to use a helper function to create a control pipe to the child process, move the file descriptors to their proper places (which is not always trivial), and fork the child process. The signature is usually similar to

```
int do_exec(pid_t *const childptr,
            const char *const cmd,
            const char *const args[],
            const int stdin_fd,
            const int stdout_fd,
            const int stderr_fd);
```

My `do_exec()` function creates a close-on-exec control pipe, to differentiate between failure to execute the child binary, and child binary exit statuses. (If the child process fails to `exec()`, it writes `errno` as a signed char to the control pipe. The parent process tries to read a single signed char from the other end of the control pipe. If that succeeds, then the exec failed; the parent reaps the child using e.g. [`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), and returns the `errno` error. Otherwise, the pipe was closed due to the exec(), so the parent process knows the child execution has started, and can close the (last open end of the) control pipe.)

Finally, if you have a multithreaded server-type process that needs to spawn new child processes with minimum latency and resource use, start a single child process connected to the original process with an Unix domain socket (because you can use ancillary messages to transfer credentials and file descriptors using those), and have that child process start the actual children. This is exactly what e.g. Apache mod_cgid and most FastCGI implementations do.

Comment: Very solid answer - you've explained a couple of different solutions and the merits of each. I'm doing something similar to 'do_exec', because the processes I spawn all serve the same, very specific purpose. An A+ answer.

Comment: There is a problem in your implementation. The loop should contain `&&` operator, else it will close even stdin, stdout and stderr

Comment: @Mildred: Yeah; good catch. I wrote "something like ..", because on all systems I've ever had access to, `STDIN_FILENO==0`, `STDOUT_FILENO==1`, and `STDERR_FILENO==2`, and I tend to use `while (fd-->3)` with no `if` clauses instead. However, your edit is correct and portable, and therefore much preferred as an example. Thanks!

Comment: `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)` should probably be `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, NULL) | FD_CLOEXEC)`.

Answer (score 2):

Either set the [`FD_CLOEXEC` (using `fcntl()`)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) on all open file descriptors before creating the new process, or have [`open()` set the `O_CLOEXEC`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) flag.

From the [posix_spawn() specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawnp.html):

> If file_actions is a null pointer, then file descriptors open in the calling process shall remain open in the child process, except for those whose close-on- exec flag FD_CLOEXEC  is  set  (see  [fcntl()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html#)  ).