# PID Pollution by launching process

Tags: linux, macos, shell, firefox-addon

On nix/mac if i launch a process with nsiProcess run or runAsync, the launching process PID gets onto the files (like locked files) etc of the launching process.

This gif shows i have one profile. I do lsof on the parentlock file, it shows one pid. I then launch a second profile, it now shows that one of the parentlock files now has multiple pid. Any ideas on how to avoid this pid pollution? via nsiprocess or jsctypes/libc methods I can use?

Oh here's the gif showing my screencast, it loops once, so if u want to repeat just a simply page refresh

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2nKL.gif

[image]

Comment: You've got two separate processes running, (two instances of firefox), so it's going to have two `PID`'s — one for each.

Comment: But the issue is the 2nd pid should not be on the `.parentlock` file of the other :(

Comment: Why are you grepping `lsof` for .parentlock though? why not `ps axc` or `ps aux`?

Comment: Not sure it just works :P But it plays a role when focusing windows by PID thats why I like lsof. Its showing there is an issue. Ill test ps axc and aux now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under unix spawning a new process is generally done by first [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)ing the parent process and then replacing the child with a new process image *in place* through [`exec()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec).

Forking causes the new process to inherit - among many other things - all file descriptors from the parent process. It may then shed some of them on calling `exec()`, but does not do so by default. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950549/close-all-file-handles-when-calling-posix-spawn) how to mark file descriptors for close-on-exec.

- If you have control over the spawned process you can just find the descriptor in question and close it.
- If you do not, then you have to write an executable which marks the descriptor for close-on-exec (see above) and then invoke `exec()` to finally start the child process you actually wanted.

  - Edit: as pointed out in the comments, there are existing programs that do just that

Comment: Thanks so much for this awesome answer. The way I solved this was by launching with `nsIProcess` the `/usr/bin/open` with these arugments: `open -a "/Applications/Firefox.app" --args -profile "blah blah" -no-remote` this luanchers firefox and closes so there is no pid polution. Your solution though helps me understand a ton so thank you very much!

Comment: Here's my snippets: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/730edc0d3517483b5100

Comment: Hey man I can't post solution because they closed the topic. But the `/usr/bin/open` was only or Mac, Nix didn't have it, so I had to use `Gio` to use `g_app_info_launch_uris` copy paste seen here: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-GioLaunch.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/dbe54fcd7794c8ddff6f)