# launchd from terminal to start app

Tags: macos, shell

I'm trying to use launchd from terminal to start app with command line arguments. I followed along here but can't figure it out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html

I'm trying to launch: `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -profile "blah blah" -no-remote`

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to directly use launchd for that and probably shouldn't.

You can just use:

```
open -a Firefox --args -profile "blah blah" -no-remote
```

Or:

```
open -a /Applications/Firefox.app --args -profile "blah blah" -no-remote
```

Or:

```
open -b org.mozilla.firefox --args -profile "blah blah" -no-remote
```

If Firefox is already running, then the above will just bring it to the front and activate it. In that case, the args are ignored because they are only meaningful when launching the app.

If you want to launch a new process even if the app is already running, pass the `-n` option to `open`, before the `--args` option. Like:

```
open -a /Applications/Firefox.app -n --args -profile "blah blah" -no-remote
```

Comment: Will test now thanks @Ken! The reason I asked this is because when I open with nsIProcess of Firefox which seems to use `posix_spawnattr_init` (im not sure im not a c guy :P) here in source: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/threads/nsProcessCommon.cpp#501  but that puts its PID on the locked files of the launching process as i posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773538/pid-pollution-by-launching-process

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! THANK YOU @KEN!! I can't tell you for how long I struggled with this!!!! AND it doesn't lock the launching process!!!! And no PID pollution!!!!!!