# Linux equivalent of OS X's /usr/bin/open

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I'm trying to launch a process such the same way that I do in OS X with `/usr/bin/open` like this: `open -a /Applications/Firefox.app --args -profile "blah blah" -no-remote`.

As I learned from this topic here: [launchd from terminal to start app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786461/launchd-from-terminal-to-start-app?lq=1).

However Linux doesn't have this `open` as I thought it did. I verified this with my searching. But in my searching I couldn't find an alternative. How can I launch process so that the launching process doesn't share its file descriptors with the launched process as explained in this SO topic: [Close all File Handles when Calling posix_spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950549/close-all-file-handles-when-calling-posix-spawn)

This is a video showing my desktop files. I'm trying to launch them somehow so that the file descriptors don't mix between each other here is my screen cast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc19BzLTnDE

This video shows the PIDs are mixing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJsyV6tK7FA

Comment: You have two completely independent problems here. Which would you like solved?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Both! ;)

Comment: Forgive that please @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I thought it was one situation. Ideally I'm looking for the best cross-linux solution to launch another process to that file descriptors aren't copied.

Comment: There isn't one. Applications that don't want their descriptors leaked should open them as close-on-exec.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah I don't want to close the launching process though, I'm trying to run firefox's in parallel, different profiles. I have profile named "default" and one named "dev". So I can launch them in parellel with command line arguments of `-no-remote -P "profile name goes here"`

Comment: Ah I don't want to close the launching process though, I'm trying to run firefox's in parallel, different profiles. I have profile named "default" and one named "dev". So I can launch them in parellel with command line arguments of `-no-remote -P "profile name goes here"`

Comment: But what does that have to do with file descriptors?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams please see this screencast I recorded it on OSX but its exact same on Linux. Doing `lsof | grep ".parent"` will show multiple PIDs on the locked file called `.parent`. Each .parent is located in the firefox profiles folder, and only ever should 1 PID be on it. :) Link to my screncast: http://i.imgur.com/OsuGbqB.gif

Comment: OH GOD, YOU WROTE AN EXTENSION TO RUN FIREFOX FROM INSIDE FIREFOX...

Comment: hahaha @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sorrry :P im trying to run from outside firefox :P

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams my extension is currently using `posix_spawn` to launch the other firefox.

Comment: I think it's unclear what's being asked here. Is it equivalent of `open`, is it file descriptors, process IDs, is it launching separate instance of Firefox, or perhaps even something else?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks @el.pescado what i mean is something does like `open` does in OSX in that it opens something on the outside, without the PID of the opened thing getting a lease on the file descriptors from the opening process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found that launches the .desktop file with the custom icon it used. I couldn't get `xdg-open` to work on i, no clue why.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/591736/any-c-functions-to-simulate-double-click-on-file/592439

Answer (score 2):

Use [xgd-open](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open).

> xdg-open is a desktop-independent tool for configuring the default applications of a user.

Comment: Except it doesn't close open descriptors.

Comment: Hi Shx2 can you please show me how to use it to launch firefox with some command line arguments: `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -no-remote -P dev` thanks very much for your fast answer!

Comment: Hi shx2 i posted a c solution at bottom which uses Gio, i couldn' fiure out xdg-open can you please share :)

Answer (score 1):

You can launch X11 applications in Linux simply by running the binary, so the `open` command is unnecessary for this use. (Another use of `open` would be to launch documents with the associated application, for which you can use either a desktop-manager-specific command or `xdg-open`.)

To avoid sharing file descriptors you can simply close them from the shell, e.g., in bash `/usr/bin/x11/firefox 3>&- 4>&- …` (up to 9) or if it's just the standard ones then perhaps you can redirect them: `</dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null`. Or maybe you just want to use `nohup` to avoid closing the program on `SIGHUP` when the terminal closes.

Comment: I'm trying to run firefox's in parallel. This I can do by attaching command line arguments of `-no-remote -P "profile name here"`, if I close the file descriptors then that will close the first instance no?